# Which file system should I use for Samba shares?

Tags: samba

Which file system should I use for Samba share with Ubuntu 14.04?

- NTFS
- ext4

or something else?

Answer (score 2):

There is no "best" for anything but if I would have been given the choice between `ext4` and `ntfs` for a Samba share on an Ubuntu server, I'd go for an `ext4` file system as that is the one the Kernel understands best and has better performance.

Just ensure that you create users both on their home system and on the Samba system.  (unless you want a "world-writable" share).

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**